# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11

Tags: java

I'm writing a simple spell checker program , but i'm having trouble with a loop and i can't seem to figure it out. Here's my code

```
public class spellchecker {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // setting up dictionary
    String[] dictionary = {"win","winner","know","born","were","plan","must","you","correct","college", "to"} ;


    //defining our sentence
    String sentence = "You were born to win but to be a winners you must plan to win prepare to win and expect to win";
    //splitting sentence into an array of words
    String[] split = sentence.split("\\s");

    for(int i = 0; i<split.length; i++)
    {
        if(split[i].equals(dictionary[0]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[1]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[2]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[3]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[4]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[5]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[6]) ||  split[i].equals(dictionary[7]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[8]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[9]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[10]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[11]))
        {
            System.out.println(split[i] + " is valid");
        }           

        else
        {
            System.out.println(split[i] + " is invalid, please correct");
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Indices for an array only run from `0` through `n - 1`.  Here, with a `dictionary` array of length 11, that's `0` through `10`.  However, you explicitly reference index `11` here:

```
|| split[i].equals(dictionary[10]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[11]))
```

You're checking all of them explicitly, starting with `0`, so just remove that last one (`11`).

```
|| split[i].equals(dictionary[10]))
```

But what if you add 5 more words to the dictionary?  50?  Your long chain of `if` conditions will also need to grow.  For flexibility, you should consider a `for` loop over all of the contents of the `dictionary` array.  Even better, consider using a `HashSet` to store your dictionary words, so that you don't have to scan the entire dictionary for every entered word.

Answer (score 1):

Your array has 11 elements (`0` - `10`).  So 11 is out of bounds.

```
split[i].equals(dictionary[11]
```

You might really want to consider using a loop in some way rather than hardcoding your indexes.

Answer (score 1):

for a more general solution, replace your big if with:

```
if(Arrays.asList(dictionary).contains(split[i]))
```

This will work for any dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `split[i].equals(dictionary[11])` from your `if()` condition

**i.e.**

Your if could be

```
if(split[i].equals(dictionary[0]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[1]) ||   split[i].equals(dictionary[2]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[3]) ||   split[i].equals(dictionary[4]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[5]) ||  split[i].equals(dictionary[6]) ||  split[i].equals(dictionary[7]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[8]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[9]) || split[i].equals(dictionary[10]))
```